# Scrapy spider scrape only 2 pages

Tags: python, scrapy

when I run this code, the spider only crawls 3 pages and stop. It doesn't go to the next page.

I tried in different ways to change and change, but I can't move to the third page with.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from realstatedata.items import RealstatedataItem

class RsdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'rsdata'
    allowed_domains = ['vivareal.com.br']
    start_urls = ['https://www.vivareal.com.br/aluguel/sp/sao-jose-dos-campos/apartamento_residencial/#preco-ate=2000']

    def parse(self, response):

        nextpageurl = response.xpath('//a[@title="Próxima página"]/@href')
        yield from self.scrape(response)

        if nextpageurl:
            path = nextpageurl.extract_first()
            nextpage = response.urljoin(path)
            print("Found url: {}".format(nextpage))
            yield scrapy.Request(nextpage, callback=self.parse)

    def scrape(self, response):
        for resource in response.xpath('//article[@class="property-card__container js-property-card"]/..'):

            item = RealstatedataItem()

            item['description'] = resource.xpath('.//h2/span[@class="property-card__title js-cardLink js-card-title"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['address'] = resource.xpath('.//span[@class="property-card__address"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['prop_area'] = resource.xpath('.//span[@class="property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value property-card__detail-area js-property-card-detail-area"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['prop_rooms'] = resource.xpath('.//span[@class="property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['prop_bath'] = resource.xpath('.//span[@class="property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['prop_parking'] = resource.xpath('.//ul/li[4]/span[@class="property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['price_rent'] = resource.xpath('.//p[@style="display: block;"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['price_cond'] = resource.xpath('.//strong[@class="js-condo-rice"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['realstate_name'] = resource.xpath('.//picture/img/@alt').extract_first()

            yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace '#' with '?' in 'path' (notice that the "next page" button doesn't work):

```
import scrapy
from realstatedata.items import RealstatedataItem

class RsdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'rsdata'
    allowed_domains = ['vivareal.com.br']
    start_urls = ['https://www.vivareal.com.br/aluguel/sp/sao-jose-dos-campos/apartamento_residencial/#preco-ate=2000']

    def parse(self, response):

        nextpageurl = response.xpath('//a[contains(@title,"Próxima página")]/@href')
        yield from self.scrape(response)

        if nextpageurl:
            path = nextpageurl.extract_first()
            # Got #pagina=2   =>    Replace with ?pagina=2
            path = '?' + path[1:]
            nextpage = response.urljoin(path)
            print("Found url: {}".format(nextpage))
            yield scrapy.Request(nextpage)

    def scrape(self, response):
        for resource in response.xpath('//article[@class="property-card__container js-property-card"]/..'):

            item = RealstatedataItem()

            item['description'] = resource.xpath('.//h2/span[@class="property-card__title js-cardLink js-card-title"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['address'] = resource.xpath('.//span[@class="property-card__address"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['prop_area'] = resource.xpath('.//span[@class="property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value property-card__detail-area js-property-card-detail-area"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['prop_rooms'] = resource.xpath('.//span[@class="property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['prop_bath'] = resource.xpath('.//span[@class="property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['prop_parking'] = resource.xpath('.//ul/li[4]/span[@class="property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['price_rent'] = resource.xpath('.//p[@style="display: block;"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['price_cond'] = resource.xpath('.//strong[@class="js-condo-rice"]/text()').extract_first()
            #item['realstate_name'] = resource.xpath('.//picture/img/@alt').extract_first()

            yield item
```

Part of output:

```
{'description': '  Apartamento com 2 Quartos para Aluguel, 82m²  '}
{'description': '  Apartamento com 4 Quartos à Venda/Aluguel 280m²  '}
{'description': '  Apartamento com 2 Quartos para Aluguel, 70m²  '}
{'description': '  Apartamento com 3 Quartos para Aluguel, 113m²  '}
{'description': '  Apartamento com 2 Quartos para Venda/Aluguel 50m²  '}
{'description': '  Apartamento com 2 Quartos para Venda/Aluguel 50m²  '}
Found url: https://www.vivareal.com.br/aluguel/sp/sao-jose-dos-campos/apartamento_residencial/?pagina=27
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i was crazy here trying to make work this code. thank you